# Why is GNU screen interfering with Vim's Ctrl-Pageup to switch tabs?

Tags: vim, terminal, keyboard-shortcuts, gnu-screen

I normally use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PageUp</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PageDown</kbd> to switch tabs in Vim. But when running Vim inside GNU screen, they don't switch tabs and instead have the effect of switching case.

I am running the following bindings in my `.screenrc`:

```
bindkey "^[[1;5D" prev
bindkey "^[[1;5C" next
```

These allow me to move between `screen` tabs with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>.

But disabling those bindings doesn't solve my problem so I don't think they are the culprit.

I am assuming there is some interaction between my terminal emulator, screen, and Vim that I don't understand.

Edit: I have found via [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6992/fixing-ctrl-in-vim-under-gnu-screen?rq=1) that starting vim with the `TERM` environment variable set (overridden) to `xterm` is a viable workaround, like this:

```
TERM=xterm vim
```

But I think the question still stands as I want to know why this is necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Normally when you run `screen` it does some initialization which (depending on the actual terminal) may change the escape sequences sent by the various keypad-keys.

For instance, I can see that it initializes `xterm`:

- application cursor keys
- application keypad

In application mode, xterm (and other terminals) change the way the unmodified special keys send escape sequences, using a different prefix (<kbd>escape</kbd><kbd>[</kbd> versus <kbd>escape</kbd><kbd>O</kbd>).  For modified keys (such as <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>PageUp</kbd>), xterm does not change its scheme.  But the terminal you are using may do this.

Since neither `screen` nor `vim` pays any attention to the terminal description for these modified keys, they would not see that the terminal description differs when running `screen`.  But you can check to see how running `screen` changes the actual strings sent by these keys, and adjust your `.screenrc` to reflect that.

You can see the actual strings using

- `cat -v` (on most systems), or
- prefixing special keys with <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>

Further reading:

- [How can I see what my keyboard sends?](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#visible_keys) (ncurses FAQ)
- [terminal database description of `screen`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#toc-_Screen)

Comment: How should I check to see the actual strings sent by these keys?